# vue + jest + typescript: Unexpected token = at class static function

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

Attempting to create unit test with jest. I've tried us ts-jest, had lots of issues. Trying babel, getting much closer. Actually got A test to work. But then I ran into this.

```
static cachedVendors = [];
                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

File looks as follows

```
//imports up here somewhere
export default class Vendor {
    public static cachedVendors: Vendor[] = [];
    ...more code
}
```

jest config

```
const { defaults: tsjPreset } = require("ts-jest/presets");

module.exports = {
    ...tsjPreset,
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.[t|j]s?$": "babel-jest",
        ".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest"
    },
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
        "^common/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/common/$1",
        "^price/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/price/$1",
        "^eligibility/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/eligibility/$1"
    }
};
```

I have removed the ...tsjPreset stuff and get the same error.

My babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [["@babel/preset-env", { targets: { node: "current" } }], "@babel/preset-typescript"],
    plugins: [["@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from"]]
};
```

As I said, I have another file I'm running test on that looks like this

```
import Vue from "vue";
import { Component, Prop, Inject, Watch } from "vue-property-decorator";
import moment from "moment";
import * as _ from "lodash";


export const DATE_FORMAT = "MM-DD-YYYY";


@Component({
})
export default class PEMDatePicker extends Vue {

    @Prop()
    label: string;

    @Prop()
    value: string;

    @Prop()
    rules: Array<Function>; //https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms#creating-rules

    public componentsLabel = "";
    public componentsDate = "";
    public showPicker = false;
    public componentsDateInput: string = moment().format("MM/DD/YYYY");

    public mounted() {

        this.componentsLabel = this.label ? this.label : "Date";
        this.setDate(this.value);

        this.$emit('input', this.value);

    }

    @Watch("value")
    public syncModel() {
        if (this.componentsDate != this.value) {

            this.setDate(this.value);
        }

        this.componentsDateInput = this.getDate;

    }

    @Watch("componentsDate")
    public syncDates() {
        this.componentsDateInput = this.getDate;
        this.$emit('input', this.componentsDate);
    }

    get getDate() {
        return this.componentsDate ? moment(this.componentsDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY") : "";
    }

    public closePicker() {
        this.showPicker = false;
        //@ts-ignore
        this.$refs.input.focus();
    }

    public handleEnterKey(event) {

        this.setDate(event.target.value);
        this.showPicker = false;
    }

    setDate(dateIn) {

        this.componentsDate = dateIn && moment(dateIn).isValid() ? moment(dateIn).format("YYYY-MM-DD") : null;
    }
}
```

This test on this file run successfully. So it's transpiling the typescript. But not on that specific file for some reason. I am at a loss.

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/babel/babelify/issues/167 
You may need to upgrade babel or add something like https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize those weren't a part of "native" typescript support. Sigh. So many moving parts with this stuff sometimes.

Comment: Yes, the advent (or at least uptick in adoption) of transpilation, polyfills, complex module loaders, and language changes over the last few years have caused a lot of hair-pulling and gnashing of teeth. Sprinkle typescript on top for added fun :)

Comment: Let me know which of those resources solved the problem and I'll add an official answer for future visitors to check. I may also edit the title so it's more google-friendly if you don't mind.

Comment: heh, it fixed that one, but then I got another one lol. Now it doesn't like my export interface ICatalogHistory.

And by it, I mean the second link. The class proposal plugin. Trying to see if there's a plugin for the interface issue as well.

Comment: And yeah, all those tools are great and provide a lot of flexibility, but man it can be a pain trying to figure out what you need where and when.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Babel is a bit conservative about new js language features (especially if you're not using the newest version of babel). In this case, you appear to need this babel plugin:

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties